# Getting 403 response code from code but 200 from web browser

Tags: java, http-proxy

I am trying to hit a public website https://reqres.in using my java code. When I make a call to https://reqres.in/api/users in web browser, browser gives the response as expected. Now when I try to do the same using java code, getting unknowhost exception for reqres.in. I tried to set the proxy using below code

```
System.setProperty("proxySet","true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","xx.xxx.xxx.xx");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","yyyy");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","xx.xxx.xxx.xx");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","yyyy");
```

After putting the above proxy, the issue got resolved. But it gives me 403 exception from code where in browser it works well.This project is build in intellij

Comment: Can you provide more information?

btw did you check if your java is behind a firewall? Or is it allowed using internet?

Comment: It is allowed to use internet. It work's well in the browser.

Comment: well 403 means forbidden request. Your request might handled as a rouge request and not properly handle by the host.